# wrap a noninheritable class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, class, types, wrapper

I would like to use a class Cookie in my namespace for convenience, with the same capabilities as System.Web.Cookie, or better be equivalent. I can't derive from System.Web.Cookie because it is noninheritable...

In C, i could simply typedef it to another type, but I don't see any possibility in VB.net other than write a wrapper class that mimics all functions.

Is there another way to "rename" a type in VB.net (Framework 4.0)?

**Edit:**

I found a solution, to import the class under a different name:

```
imports Cookie = System.Web.HttpCookie
```

But I would still be interested in other solutions. 
Therefore I didn't add this as answer.

Comment: Why would it be more convenient for it to be in your namespace? Creating marker classes isn't good practice. Creating class and object adaptors is only really a good pattern when you're trying to alter the API provided to the user to make it consistent with other things you're wrapping. I'm not sure what actual "problem" you're trying to solve.

Comment: Because I would like to have a consistent framework but not reinvent all classes when there already are good implementations like HttpCookie. So I want to use HttpCookie, but name it the way I want. :) Is this possible?

Comment: You have a consistent framework already, it's called the .NET framework. Don't reinvent the wheel, don't hijack somebody else's wheel. By doing this you're almost certainly going to introduce defects, readability issues and compatibility issues.

Comment: Well, thanks for the tip, but I prefer working with things in a way I want them to be. That means using parts I like from .NET framework,  adapting others and (re-)inventing the rest.

Comment: @gpinkas Hey, finally do you found a solution? I'm really interested on it... you can answer to my question if you prefer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936389/how-i-could-import-use-all-the-native-methods-of-an-static-class-into-a-custom-c thanks.