# How I could Import/Implement all the native methods of an static Class into a custom Class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, class

I have this Class

```
Imports _Console = System.Console

Public Class ConsoleEx ' : Inherits _Console

    Public Shared Sub MyCustomMethod()
        ' Do something
    End Sub

End Class
```

And my idea is just to use that Class as a **FULL** qualified replacement of the `Console` Class then I would like to be able to use **ALL** the `Console` class methods as normally but from my custom `ConsoleEx` class together with my custom methods, for example:

```
' Native Console class method:
ConsoleEx.WriteLine(Parametters)

' My custom method:
ConsoleEx.MyCustomMethod(Parametters)
```

I'm not lazy but I imagine that this could be possibly to do it in one step? Framework does not provide anything to do it?

Which is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i know this is not really an answer but i cannot comment yet)

I think what you are looking for is some sort of inheritance system but the Console class cannot be inherited.
So i think its not possible to do in "one simple step"

[Link to MSDN console class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the info, here is another similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945737/wrap-a-noninheritable-class-in-vb-net and I were googling for how to create a wrapper class but I don't find anything (and only just the technique name scares me, seems to be really hard like wrapping 3rd-party libraries for adapt them to .NET, but well if that is the only solution then I will try it)